# How to translate dates?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, datetime

I have a calendar view in my Drupal 7 website, that looks like this:

[image: Calendar]

And I also have a date field in a Webform:

[image: Entering date in Webform]

All of these appear in english, of course. But, I want to translate all dates to portuguese.

How can I do that easily?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Drupal contributed modules have their translation under [Drupal Translations](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads)

If you visit the site and search for Date, you will notice list of countries and languages.

I notice Portuguese translations for Date module.

1. Portuguese, Brazil
2. Portuguese, International
3. Portuguese, Portugal

Download the correct language translation file by selecting the version of Date module your using.

Go to http://[your_site]/admin/config/regional/translate/import . To import the downloaded file.

For more information about Translation and how to build multi language site please refer to my answer in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/184623/24038

Comment: I did as you said. I had to enable the "Locale" module in order to be able to import the ".po" file. But after uploading the language file, nothing changed. I changed the language to portuguese. I changed it in the Calendar View also. But it still remains in english. Could you help me out, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: @joaorodr84 did you clear your cache?

Also under filed, make sure to tick the box make field translatable.

Comment: Meanwhile, I fixed it. Maybe that was the problem. It works now. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Make field translatable does not enable it showing dates in proper translated format; it allows the version of your node in lang1 to have a different date than the version in lang2.